# Jest TLSWRAP open handle error using simple node-postgres pool.query() fixed with setTimeout delay, but why?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, node-postgres

When I run the following test:

```js
afterAll(async () => {
    await runDbBuild();
    await pool.end();
});

describe("queries.newteetypes.select.all():", () => {
        test("Test 1: object keys ", async () => {
            const awaitedResponse = await queries.newteetypes.select.all();
            expect(awaitedResponse).toStrictEqual(anticipatedResponse);
    });
});
```

I get this error: `Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:`
[image: screenshot of error]

The above code that is shown works absolutely fine in production. The issue is only with `jest` giving me a potential open handles warning.

I can fix it by introducing a delay with a `setTimeout()` and `Promise`, but the placement baffles me. Here's the solution (same code but with one line added above the query call):

```js
afterAll(async () => {
    await runDbBuild();
    await pool.end();
});

describe("queries.newteetypes.select.all():", () => {
        test("Test 1: object keys ", async () => {
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000)); // Putting a delay before the query solves the problem, but putting the delay after the query doesn't resolve it.
            const awaitedResponse = await queries.newteetypes.select.all();
            expect(awaitedResponse).toStrictEqual(anticipatedResponse);
    });
});
```

This seems very counter-intuitive to me. Initially I tried putting the timeout in the `afterAll()` function, but it didn't make any difference no matter where I included it. So then I experimented by putting it after the query call, within the `test()` function, but that didn't work. When I put it **before** the query call, I stop receiving the error. But why would that make a difference?

Comment: Wow, I am fighting this exact issue.  So far I found nothing to help, BUT pasting your 2 second timer above my pool.connect() solved it.  Very, very odd.  At any rate, I think that helps narrow it toward connection issue versus query issue.

Answer (score 7):

Treat your "new Pool( ...)" as a promise and `await` for it:

```
async function createPool () {
  return await new Pool({ connectionString })
}
```

Your findings of `setTimeout`, had me try this with the same successful result:

```
await process.nextTick(() => {})
```

Placing that right before my `connect()` worked.   So from there I started backing up to the "earliest" point that adding a `process.nextTick` would fix the issue and it appears to be solved by just treating `new Pool(..)` as a promise.

Perhaps the pool is willing to start dishing out clients before it's completely ready to track them under the hood?  That might be why the extra `await` up front solves this.

This could very much be related to why people are not able to close clients or the pool properly -- because something about the pool management is mangled.  For example:  https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2341

Comment: Ah I'm so relieved that I'm not alone with this! I'll check your solution out when I'm looking at the back end next. Thanks for sharing - I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Yeah, would be helpful to know if it fixes your issue.   I posted some commentary at the github site:  https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2648

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense - constructors in JavaScript can't be async (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363278/can-async-await-be-used-in-constructors) so `await new Pool()` or `await new Anything()` shouldn't be any different from the same code without `await`.

Comment: @mikemaccana It depends on what node-postgres is doing underneath the hood doesn't it?   For example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885340/2957186   I didn't dive into what node-postgres is doing, but that added await definitely solves the problem.   If you dive in and find a better/more appropriate solution (probably easy to do), I'll edit this solution and point to yours.

Comment: @alfreema I'm afraid it doesn't - there is not a single JS implementation where a constructor can return a `Promise<Object>` rather than `<Object>`.

Comment: The idea of this answer seems OK but the way to properly clean-up the pool is likely different. In my case, it was sufficient to await `pool.end()` after the tests.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this with integration tests that use Axios and it works:
`await new Promise(resolve => process.nextTick(resolve))`