# Jest has detected open handle for firstValueFrom in nestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I get this error with firstValueFrom when using NestJS + Axios HttpService.

> Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

`await firstValueFrom(this.httpService.get(url, { headers }));`

But at the same time, jest completes successfully and my requests do not hang. What is the right thing to do in this situation?

Don't suggest `--forceExit` :)

**UPD #1:**

```
public async getData() {
    const url = 'correct url here :) ';
    const headers = {};
    return await firstValueFrom(this.httpService.get(url, { headers }));
}
```

Test:

```
describe('Service', () => {
    describe('Main', () => {
        it('get data', async () => {
            const result = await service.getData();
            expect(result.data).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same exception when using `lastValueFrom`?

Comment: yep, same exception

Comment: Can you show your test? I haven't seen this happen before with the `@nestjs/axios` package

Comment: Added test in main question

Comment: no idea why it works but `await process.nextTick(() => { });` [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169492/async-external-function-leaves-open-handles-jest-supertest-express)